# Multiple ordered lists boiled down to one list, where order is relative

Tags: c#, sorting, diff

I have multiple ordered lists.  Unfortunately, the order of the items isn't a simple alpha or numeric comparison, otherwise this is trivial.  So what I have is something like:

```
List #1        List #2       List #3
groundhog      groundhog     easter
mothersday     mayday        mothersday
midsummer      laborday      halloween
christmas
```

And from this I can gather than groundhog < mothersday, but the relationship of groundhog and easter is unknown.  I am guaranteed that the order of the items from list-to-list is self consistent.  (i.e. that no matter which list it occurs in, easter is always before halloween)

But what I need is a new ordered list that represents each item in the other lists only once, that preserves all of the known relationships above:

```
groundhog
easter
mayday
mothersday
midsummer
laborday
halloween
christmas
```

However, the following list is also perfectly valid:

```
easter
groundhog
mothersday
mayday
midsummer
laborday
halloween
christmas
```

I'm looking for a fairly quick, general-purpose algorithm I can use to order N lists in this way.   (Working C# code a plus, for sure, but not necessary.)

I have solution that works, but its O(N^2) and a dog with even modest data sets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to have a look at [topological sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sort). I think it applies quite well to your case.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @bdumitriu, you want topological sorting.

This type of sort assumes you have a *partial order* among your data items, which means that for *certain pairs* of items, you can compare them to see which one precedes the other.  In this case, like you say, there are multiple ways to create a single list of the items that preserves all of the constraints.

Topological sort usually works by first creating a directed acyclic graph of your items, where each item becomes a vertex, and a directed edge from node X to node Y means item X precedes item Y in your input lists.  (So you'd walk through your set of input sorted lists, and every time you encounter a new item, you'd make a vertex for it, and for every consecutive pair of items in each sorted list, you make a directed edge from the first item to the second.  Note that you don't need to create directed edges from an item to *all* of the previous items in each input list; for example in your input List 1, you'd create edges `groundhog` -> `mothersday`, `mothersday` -> `midsummer`, and `midsummer` -> `christmas`.)

A topological sort will take time O(V+E), where V is the total number of items you are sorting (the number of vertices), and E is the total number of predecessor relationships from your input lists (the number of edges).

--Phil

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Array.Sort method, with a Comparison method that takes the two strings to be compared, and then checks their presence in any list; any list which has them both, find their relative positions, and return based upon that; if no list has them both, return equality.

The MSN documentation states that their sorting algorthm uses a quicksort; averaging nlog(n) order, with worst case being on the order of n^2.

This way, you get to leverage their implementation of the sorting algorithm; all you have to do is implement the comparison code.